# failed to load given url and linking css file

Tags: java, jsp

```
CMS    
-webcontent
--css
---style.css
--images
---frontpage.jpg
-index.jsp
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WebContent/images/frontpage.jpg" media="screen" />

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<center>

</center>
<img alt="" src="WebContent/images/frontpage.jpg" />

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

#wrap{ 
width: 1100px; 
background:#FFFFE8;
margin-top: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

plz help me i'm stuck with this

unable to show image and link css with index page

don't know what is wrong

i have tried many diffrent approches but unable to solve this

Comment: Can you post the error in the dev console?

Comment: Have you tried typing the URL of your image or stylesheet directly into your browser? If you're getting a 404 error it's probably an indication that something about your path is wrong (e.g. webcontent vs. WebContent).

Comment: nothing shows except jsp textand i'm getting no error